# Page header confusion

Tags: header-footer

Using `\newpagestyle` I wanted to put the section title in the page header. However on the 1st page with the first section I have the header of the second section, as the example shows:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[sf,bf,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\pagina{}

\newpagestyle{main}{\headrule%
    \sethead{}{\footnotesize\it\pagina}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{main}

\newcommand\sectionX[1]{%
    \section*{#1}%
    \renewcommand\pagina{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\sectionX{Uno}

\framebox{We have here header ``Due''. WHY?}

\bigskip

\lipsum[1]

\sectionX{Due}

\lipsum[2]

\sectionX{Tre}

\lipsum[3]

\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: The header is updated before LaTeX decides that the section needs to be put on a new page.

Comment: Is your only purpose to get unnumbered section headings?

Comment: How to correct this situation? The hard-page seems to be rather strange solution.

Comment: The second comment of me was much more important. If you are only after unnumbered headings, the solutions is amazingly simple.

Comment: I want to have more complex header than in the example code. This is the minimum which makes problems.

Answer (score 1):

That's why there are marks. These pick up information at the time the page is built.

Here is a solution with fanchdr. [Actually I would suggest not to redefine your own section command, but I just kept it.]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{\footnotesize\textit{\rightmark}}
\rhead{\thepage}

\newcommand\sectionX[1]{%
    \section*{#1}%
    \markright{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
```

The rest is the same.

Comment: Thank you. However the `fancyhdr` not always work fine. `\markright` with `titlesec` is strange. Is there any simple solution for the `titlesec`?

Comment: I don't know. Do you have an example where it is strange?